# mysql check values from sub query

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

**** SOLVED ****

```
SELECT price
FROM inventory
WHERE price > ANY (SELECT price FROM inventory WHERE type = 'new');
```

Thank you to Mohammed Shafeek and every one else that commented.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am trying to check if a price is higher than any of the prices in a sub-query.

```
SELECT price
FROM inventory
WHERE price > price IN (SELECT price FROM inventory WHERE type = 'new');
```

So I want to be able to check if a price is higher than at least one of the values from the sub-query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**** EDIT ****

Example of what i mean

$20 > $15, $30, $50

So because $20 is greater than $15 it would be selected

Would this be Min(price)

Like mentioned in below comments

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT price
FROM inventory
WHERE price > ANY (SELECT price FROM inventory WHERE type = 'new');
```

I think this is the query actually u want.Check it

Answer (score 2):

One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT price
FROM inventory
WHERE price > (SELECT MAX(price) FROM inventory WHERE type = 'new');
```

Another uses the `ALL` operator:

```
SELECT price
FROM inventory
WHERE price > ALL (SELECT price FROM inventory WHERE type = 'new');
```

Comment: Can't compete with you at all on speed either, Gordon :)

Comment: would this work if the value is greater than just one of the values in the sub query so for example

$20 > $20, $40, $60

would still be selected because it is higher than one of the sub query values

Comment: in first query ,he was asking "check if a price is higher than any of the prices in a sub-query"..then instead of MAX(price).. i think MIN(price) is more better..

Comment: @MohammedShafeek . . . I interpreted that as all.  You can use `ANY` rather than `ALL`.